# Inefficient UICollectionView ... how to optimize?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I am implementing a `UICollectionView`.

In the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, I am alloc initing a class with a handful of outlets and a handful of custom buttons, labels, textviews (so drawRect is being called for each of these custom buttons and labels).

Everytime each cell comes on screen, alloc init gets called ... causing the scrolling to be choppy.

My question is whether there is a more efficient implementation. I understand that `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: forIndexPath:` is the cause of this (I think) and I understand the point of it but is it possible to optimize a little more than what I have right now?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: It is not possible to optimize your code without seeing your code.

Comment: init method will call everytime, coz cell is reusable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things:

1. Make sure the cell is opaque (along with all of its subviews).  This is the #1 cause of scroll lag in UICollectionViews in my experience.  Get rid of any transparencies as the most likely culprit.
2. If that fails, go to the Debug menu in the simulator and select "Color Blended Layers".  This will highlight layers in red that are sneaking in alpha channels and being redrawn.
3. If that fails try the Core Animation tool in Instruments and see where the framerate is chopping.  Use time profiler as well and find your hotspots.

I'm pretty sure #1 and #2 are going to give you what you need though, it's an extremely common error.

Answer (score 1):

I have to add that another big culprit is `UITextView`. I have `UITextView`s with link detections, and due to a bug in iOS 7, I have to `nil` the text property everytime... Seems like that causes a lot of CPU hogging, resulting in dropped frames.

A simple fix for my case (max 20 `UITextViews`) was to cache them when calculating the height of the cells. I am considering a cached `textStorage`, too, but this works for now.